# Windows Mobile Phone Book API for C#

Tags: .net, windows-mobile

I wanted know what are the API used to get the contact numbers from phone book using C# for Windows Mobile. If anybody has source code example please give code snippets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check usage of OutlookSession in the example in the Windows Mobile SDK:

Windows Mobile 6 SDK\Samples\Smartphone\CS\SmsIM\

Answer (score 2):

Check out this blogpost: http://milandinic.blogspot.com/2009/02/c-windows-mobile-api-for-contacts.html